# How do I know if it's antisymmetric or not

Tags: discrete-mathematics

For $x = 2y$, it is antisymmetric because $x = 2y$ and $y = 2x$ $\implies$ $x = 4x$ $\implies$ $x = 0$ $\implies$ $x = 2x = y = 0$. I found this solution from textbook.

However, for $x + 2y = 0$, is it antisymmetric? I did similar prove that $x = -2y,\ y = -2x$ $\implies$ $x = 4x$ so $x = 0$ $\implies$ $x = -2x = y = 0$.

I am not sure if it is working or not. 
And to prove that it is false, I know that we can use counter-example, but for this case (that I proved) would using an example work? 
I am so confused and I am not sure if it's correct.

Comment: Please be explicit about the relation you are working with. Presumably you mean $x R y$ if $x+2y=0$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you mean, $xRy$ holds if and only if $x+2y=0$ we can proceed as follows.

Let's assume that both $aRb$ and $bRa$ holds for some numbers $a$ and $b$. 
Then from the definition of $R$ the following holds,

$a+2b=0$.

$b+2a=0$.

Solving the above equations we get $a=b=0$.

By the definition, $R$ is antisymmetric if and only if $aRb$ and $bRa$ implies $a=b$. This condition is satisfied here since $R=\{(0,0)\}$.